# Xcode Playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

In an Xcode Playground you can click the little circle next to the eye and it should show the console, however when I click mine it just shows the quick view box near the code. How can I correct this and set it back to default? I believe it originally worked like that but now does not.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

> you can click the little circle next to the eye and it should show the console

I don't think that's right. I see the same result you do: clicking the eye pops open the Quick Look pane. This is exactly the same thing that happens when you point at a variable in a project while debugging: you can click the eye icon and see the contents of the variable in a Quick Look pane.

To open the console in a project or a playground, use the View->Debug Area->Activate Console command.